# Search for large primes

Tags: number-theory

I posted this recently on a different board and have now thought to share it here.

I believe the following will prove to be an efficient method for finding very large primes.  In particular, I believe it could well be used to find a new largest prime number.

In the search for large primes and semi-primes one should test numbers of the form:

$$ N = p(x) - 2y^n $$

where $p(x)$ is $3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 11\cdot \ldots \cdot x$ and $x$ is some last prime in the consecutive list, $y\gt x$ and $y$ is prime, $n$ is largest possible that yields positive N.

Smaller $n$ works with reduced probability of prime.

My question: Is there merit in this idea?

Comment: Computing that product is very costly - you have to compute the primes up to $x$ and then one more. Do you have prove that the result is prime? I'm not seeing it. You could, of course, subtract $2^my^n$, which will get you smaller values.

Comment: Do you have a more focused question to ask?  If you find the construction interesting (and apparently you do), then of course that is a merit of your idea.  But surely you are motivated to do something more with the idea?  It would be of wider interest if you proposed some basis for comparison with other approaches.

Comment: It is very hard to beat the largest known Mersenne-prime-number. I do not think that the method will do it. It is much more likely that a larger Mersenne-prime-number is found. Another problem is to prove the primality of a number $N$ , which can be unfeasible if both $N-1$ and $N+1$ cannot be factored.

Answer (score 1):

Whether there is merit in this idea depends on why you want to find specific large primes. I am not aware of a mathematical interest in finding specific large primes aside from the largest known.  If you are using large primes for encryption, it might be attractive to have a formula that generates primes with higher probability than "random" numbers.  Unfortunately, if the bad guys find out you are using this formula, they can probably find your prime easily as the search space is greatly reduced.  Why do you think primes are denser here than in "random" numbers of this size (roughly $1$ in $\log N$)?